# Find Pattern in consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, r

Whats the most effective method to detect n Pattern in consecutive numbers?
Maybe an SQL column or vector, R.
Some Pseudocode -R- to illustrate the "problem":

```
find Pattern in consecutive integers, where 
2nd integer < 1st integer, 
3rd integer > 2nd integer & 
4th integer > 3rd integer.


a <- x
b <- x +1 < a
c <- x +2 > b
d <- x +3 > c

pattern <- c(a, b, c, d)
example: pattern <- c(10, 8, 9, 11) or pattern <- c(2.11, 2.08, 2.09, 2.11)

count(pattern)
find(pattern)
```

Comment: "Pseudocode" means; only for "Illustration".

Comment: "Pseudocode" means "write this code for me"

Comment: Sorry for the question.
There was no Option for me to describe the problem more accurate.

Comment: If you don't even know how the data is stored, then I think the question is too broad.

Comment: PostgreSQL [10.0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the difference of the vector then the first should be negative and the other two positive, so,

```
a <- c(10, 8, 9, 11)

all((diff(a) < 0) == c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
#[1] TRUE
```

To apply that to a bigger vector, you can use `rollapply` from `zoo` package, i.e.

```
library(zoo)

a <- sample(1:100,100,replace=T)
unique(rollapply(a, 4, by = 1, function(i) i[all((diff(i) < 0) == c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))]))
```

which gives,

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
>  [1,]   85   18   85   92
>  [2,]   44   27   67   76
>  [3,]   58    2   39   54
>  [4,]   85   69   82   84
>  [5,]   61    4   40   44
>  [6,]   65   58   73   97
>  [7,]   19    9   92   96
>  [8,]   33   24   57   73
>  [9,]   79   11   37  100
> ```

Comment: Close!
But if you try this with an longer vector/column and you expect, lets say, 5 patterns:

    `a <- sample(1:100,100,replace=T) 

    all((diff(a) < 0) == c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
`

There is maybe an pattern from 3 to 7 & 23 to 27 …

Comment: @Teletubbi-OSX You need to do a rolling window apply. package `zoo` is perfect for that. Let me edit

Comment: Cool! Thx!
Shame on me that I never heared about "zoo" before! ;)